# Splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb Q$ are distinct but isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

What I'm trying to solve is:
Prove that given the polynomial $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb Q$, its splitting fields $\Bbb Q(x_1)$ , $\Bbb Q(x_2)$ , $\Bbb Q(x_3)$ are isomorphic but distinct (where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial).

What I've tried so far:
I managed to prove they are isomorphic, but how do I go about the distinction between them? Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Hint: one of them is contained in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Those aren't splitting fields. A splitting field would be $\Bbb Q(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Assuming we are working inside $\Bbb C$, there is only one splitting field over $\Bbb Q$ for each polynomial.

Comment: @Arthur would Q[cubic_root(2)] be a splitting field of that polynomial? And $Q[x]/(x^2-3)$ ? Bytheway I’ve already showed it. How do I show that Q(x2) and Q(x3) are distinct?

Comment: By definition of splitting field, a splitting field for $f$ must contain *all* the roots of $f$. As for showing those fields are distinct, can you use Galois Theory, or are you just starting out on the road that leads to Galois Theory so you can't use it yet?

Comment: I guess without Galois Theory, you could show that ${\bf Q}(x_2,x_3)$ is a splitting field for $x^3-2$ and has degree six over the rationals, so $x_3$ must have degree two over ${\bf Q}(x_2)$, etc.

Comment: No, none of those are splitting fields. $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ can't split $\frac{x^3-2}{x-\sqrt[3]2}=x^2+\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[3]4$. And from there you can conclude that no degree-3 extension of the rationals can contain all three (or even any two) roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson we briefly talked about field extension in a linear algebra course in order to talk about minimal polynomial, and other things. I don’t know Galois Theory, we only talked about rings of polynomials and their splitting fields. We know Q(x1) as the set of elements of the form $a+b*x1+c*x1^2$ where a, b and c are elements of Q and $x1^3 = 2$

Comment: If you're going to spend much time on this website, Matteo, it would be wise to put a little time into learning how to format math here. $x_1$ looks much better than x1, and $\root3\of2$ than cubic_root(2). Help is available by way of the help menu.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much indeed @Gerry Myerson I’ll read some documentation about how to use this formatting, and sorry for bothering you, but how would you show that the two are distinct? Could you explain further how you would show it? Thank you.

Comment: OK, Matteo, you have two answers posted now. Any thoughts on them?

Comment: Come on, Matteo. Not polite to post a question and then disappear when you get some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let the zeros of $f(x)=x^3-2$ be $x_1=\root3\of2$, $x_2=\rho x_1$, and $x_3=\rho^2 x_1$, where $\rho=e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Note that $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$, so any field containing two of the three zeros also contains the third.

$x_1$ is real, and of degree three over the rationals.

$x_2$ is not real, so it isn't in $K={\bf Q}(x_1)$, so $K$ is not a splitting field for $f$. $x_2$ is a zero of $(x^3-2)/(x-x_1)=x^2+x_1x+x_1^2$ so it's of degree two over $K$ (not degree one, since we know it's not in $K$).

$L=K(x_2)$ contains all the zeros of $f$, and no smaller field does, so $L$ is a splitting field for $f$. Since $L$ has degree two over $K$, and $K$ has degree three over the rationals, $L$ has degree six over the rationals.

${\bf Q}(x_2,x_3)$ contains all the zeros of $f$, so it contains (in fact, *is*) a splitting field for $f$, so it has degree at least (in fact, *exactly*) six over the rationals, so $x_3$ isn't in ${\bf Q}(x_2)$ (if it were, then ${\bf Q}(x_2,x_3)$, of degree at least six, would equal ${\bf Q}(x_2)$, of degree three, which is nonsense). Therefore, ${\bf Q}(x_2)$ and ${\bf Q}(x_3)$ are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$ be the real root. That's obviously distinct from the other two. Suppose $\mathbb{Q}(x_2)=\mathbb{Q}(x_3)$. Then, $x_2,x_3$ are in the same extension, w.l.o.g. let it be $\mathbb{Q}(x_2)$. Since $x_1x_2x_3=2$, that implies $x_1$ is also in $\mathbb{Q}(x_2)$. So $\mathbb{Q}(x_1)\subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(x_2)$. Which is impossible.

Comment: Actually, the product of the roots is $2$, not $-2$.

Comment: Right, thanks, I have updated it.